# Convert nested array into array of objects problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to convert this nested array data into an array of objects. Here is the data.

```
  const tableData = [
    ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
    ["June", "Gregory", "Hammond", "IN"],
    ["James", "Wynn", "Gary", "IN"],
    ["Craig", "Norman", "Schererville", "IN"]
  ]
```

Here is what the output should be

```
[
  { first_name : "June", last_name : "Gregory", city: "Hammond", state : "IN" },
  { first_name : "James", last_name : "Wynn", city: "Gary", state : "IN" },
  { first_name : "Craig", last_name : "Norman", city: "Schererville", state : "IN" }
]
```

Here is my code.

```
    function convertTable(table_data) {
var result = []
var key, value
for (var i=0; i<table_data.length; i++) {
  var employee = {}
  for (var j=0; j<table_data[i].length; j++) {
    key = table_data[i][j][0]
    value = table_data[i][j][1]
    employee[key] = value
   }
   result.push(employee)
  }
  return result
 }

  var input = [
    ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
    ["June", "Gregory", "Hammond", "IN"],
    ["James", "Wynn", "Gary", "IN"],
    ["Craig", "Norman", "Schererville", "IN"]
  ]

console.log(convertTable(input));
```

The solution is printing out the first letters of the words instead of the whole word. I am having a hard time understanding why. I ask if any commenters could leave comments line by line to help aid my understanding of this program. I wrote it with assistance of researching similar problems but still having a hard time understanding. I have been reading about Javascript on w3schools, MDN, and watching Youtube videos on explanations. Any other help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please, take a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If the answer where helpful to you take care of follow those suggestions. Just remember that people spend time and effort helping you and will appreciate some feedback from you. There are some nice answers down there...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you took for both values a single character, which is not necessary,

```
key = table_data[i][j][0]
//                    ^^^
value = table_data[i][j][1]
//                      ^^^
```

then you need two changes, one for the outer loop to omit the keys and inside use the first row for the keys. Please see in the code the comments.

The other change is to declare all variable at top of the function.

```js
function convertTable(table_data) {
    var result = [],
        key, value,
        employee,
        i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < table_data.length; i++) {        // start from index 1
        employee = {};
        for (j = 0; j < table_data[i].length; j++) {
            key = table_data[0][j];                  // take the value form index zero
                                                     // no following index for the letter
            value = table_data[i][j];                // no following index for the letter
            employee[key] = value;
        }
        result.push(employee);
    }
    return result;
}

var input = [["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"], ["June", "Gregory", "Hammond", "IN"], ["James", "Wynn", "Gary", "IN"], ["Craig", "Norman", "Schererville", "IN"]]

console.log(convertTable(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Different approach

```js
function convertTable(table) {
    return table
        .slice(1)
        .map(a => Object.assign(...table[0].map((k, i) => ({ [k]: a[i] }))));
}

var input = [["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"], ["June", "Gregory", "Hammond", "IN"], ["James", "Wynn", "Gary", "IN"], ["Craig", "Norman", "Schererville", "IN"]]

console.log(convertTable(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You just misplaced some index except that everything is fine.
Just match with your function and you can find easily where you missed.

```js
  const tableData = [
    ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
    ["June", "Gregory", "Hammond", "IN"],
    ["James", "Wynn", "Gary", "IN"],
    ["Craig", "Norman", "Schererville", "IN"]
  ]


    function convertTable(table_data) {
var result = []
var key, value
for (var i=1; i<table_data.length; i++) {
  var employee = {}
  for (var j=0; j<table_data[i].length; j++) {
    key = table_data[0][j]
    value = table_data[i][j]
    employee[key] = value
   }
   result.push(employee)
  }
  return result
 }

  var input = [
    ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
    ["June", "Gregory", "Hammond", "IN"],
    ["James", "Wynn", "Gary", "IN"],
    ["Craig", "Norman", "Schererville", "IN"]
  ]

console.log(convertTable(input));
```

```css
  { first_name : "June", last_name : "Gregory", city: "Hammond", state : "IN" },
  { first_name : "James", last_name : "Wynn", city: "Gary", state : "IN" },
  { first_name : "Craig", last_name : "Norman", city: "Schererville", state : "IN" }
] */
```

Answer (score 0):

You was accessing a `3-level` deep on the root array, so you where indexing the strings inside the `2-level` arrays.

Using this: `key = table_data[i][j][0]` you was accessing the first character of the `j-placed` string inside the array on index `i`.

And using this: `value = table_data[i][j][1]` you was accessing the second character of the `j-placed` string inside the array on index `i`.

Also, you already know the first array are the keys (or headers), so you don't want to loop on it. Check next example:

```js
function convertTable(table_data)
{
    var result = [];
    var key, value;
    
    for (var i = 1; i < table_data.length; i++)
    {
        var employee = {};

        for (var j = 0; j < table_data[i].length; j++)
        {
            key = table_data[0][j];
            value = table_data[i][j];
            employee[key] = value;
        }

        result.push(employee);
     }
     
     return result;
 }

  var input = [
    ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
    ["June", "Gregory", "Hammond", "IN"],
    ["James", "Wynn", "Gary", "IN"],
    ["Craig", "Norman", "Schererville", "IN"]
  ]

console.log(convertTable(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains three errors which can be fixed as follows:

1. Start iterating your outer loop from `i = 1` to skip headers, which are at index 0.
2. Index into the headers array with `tableData[0][j]` instead of `tableData[i][j][0]`, which is one dimension too many (accessing characters) and incorrectly includes the row index `i`.
3. Index into your data table with `tableData[i][j]` instead of `tableData[i][j][1]`, which again accesses characters within your strings.

Beyond this, I recommend paying attention to spacing, semicolons and camelCasing conventions. This will make your code easier to understand and debug.

Putting it together yields:

```js
function convertTable(tableData) {
  var result = [];
  var key;
  var value;
  
  for (var i = 1; i < tableData.length; i++) { // start at 1 to skip headers
    var employee = {};
    
    for (var j = 0; j < tableData[i].length; j++) {
      key = tableData[0][j];   // remove character index and use [0][j]
      value = tableData[i][j]; // remove character index
      employee[key] = value;
    }
    
    result.push(employee);
  }
  
  return result;
}

var input = [
  ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
  ["June", "Gregory", "Hammond", "IN"],
  ["James", "Wynn", "Gary", "IN"],
  ["Craig", "Norman", "Schererville", "IN"]
];

console.log(convertTable(input));
```

Beyond that, this is a great task for array functions `map` and `reduce` to perform the CSV to object conversion. `shift()` pops the headers off the front of the array, `map` loops over rows and applies `reduce` to each one. `reduce` builds an object using `i` and `j` row/column indices to reference the headers array in the same manner as your function.

```js
const tableData = [
  ["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"],
  ["June", "Gregory", "Hammond", "IN"],
  ["James", "Wynn", "Gary", "IN"],
  ["Craig", "Norman", "Schererville", "IN"]
];

const headers = tableData.shift();
const result = tableData.map((e, i) => 
  e.reduce((a, f, j) => {
    a[headers[j]] = f;
    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise version using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const data = [["first_name", "last_name", "city", "state"], ["June", "Gregory", "Hammond", "IN"], ["James", "Wynn", "Gary", "IN"], ["Craig", "Norman", "Schererville", "IN"]]

const result = data.reduce((r,c,i,arr) => {
  if(i) r.push(c.reduce((a,b,j) => (a[arr[0][j]] = b, a), {}))
  return r
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

The idea is to go trough the data skipping the first/header row and then keep pushing to the accumulator the composed objects from the inner `reduce` which simply decorates and empty object with the values from the header (as key) and the current array (as value)

Comment: –1, not enough reduce ;)

Comment: :) is there ever such thing as "enough reduce"?